# In Swift, how do I trigger an event to occur when an item is deleted from UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using Swift 3.1 and I have a table in one of my viewcontrollers. When the user deletes one of the items in the table by swiping left and pressing the red delete button, I want an alert message to pop up and say something. My code below is not being triggered for some reason, when I swipe left to delete something from my UITableView table. See the 10 or so lines below where I marked my attempt with "CODE HERE". Is there any way I can get this code to trigger when something is deleted?

```
import UIKit

class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var checkoutButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

var items: [String] = []

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return items.count

}


// CODE HERE

func table(table: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func table(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:   UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sample Title", message: "Sample message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// CODE HERE    


internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 16
    cell.textLabel?.font = cell.textLabel?.font.withSize(10)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")


    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

        items = tempItems

    }

    table.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        table.reloadData()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

    }

}


@IBAction func checkoutClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
    items.removeAll()
    table.reloadData()
    totalPrice = 0
    priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should present your alert in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        table.reloadData()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

    }

}
```

Full code:

```
import UIKit

class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkoutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    var items: [String] = []

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items.count

    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 16
        cell.textLabel?.font = cell.textLabel?.font.withSize(10)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
        let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")


        if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

            items = tempItems

        }

        table.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            table.reloadData()

            UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sample Title", message: "Sample message", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }


    @IBAction func checkoutClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
        items.removeAll()
        table.reloadData()
        totalPrice = 0
        priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalPrice)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the use of `UserDefaults`? And why would you reload the whole table just to delete one row?

Comment: @rmaddy it is the method from the provided code, it's not my solution

Comment: Oh. I didn't scroll down enough. There are actually two `commitEditingStyle` methods in the code - one with the wrong signature and one with the right signature.

Comment: @rmaddy yep, there are two of them (:

Comment: @shampouya I'm glad I helped. Please, also check the 2nd answer, rmaddy gave some good suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You have two attempts at the `commit` method. One with the wrong signature and one with the correct signature. Your use of the alert is in the wrong one. You really need to clean up your code and remove all of the wrong methods. Then put the desired functionality in the correct methods.

And why do you have all of those needless `!` operators on so many of the method parameters?